# how to filter certain records from my table - bigquery

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

I have a table that has `product_name,groups(a,b,c,d)`
I want to get all products that are in groups `a,b` and `d` but not `c`.

I gave below query but I am not getting expected results

```
SELECT
prod_name,group, COUNT(group) AS Count
FROM
  [prod.table]
WHERE
prod NOT IN('c')
AND prod IN('a'.'b','d')
```

[image: table below]

From the above table, the query has to fetch only prod2 as it is not in group c.

I can do this easily using pivot table by just excluding group `c` alone and including `a,b,d`. I am looking for something similar.

Comment: what is your result? error?

Comment: no error but when i verify the product to check in what all groups it is present, it also shows group c

Comment: provide example of your data  - just few rows will be enough

Comment: product group
Prod1 a
Prod1 b
Prod1 c
Prod1 d
PRod2 a
Prod2 b
Prod2 d
Prod3 a
Prod3 b
Prod3 c
Prod3 d

Comment: can you put this in  your question so it is clear what the columns are and the values in them. reading this in  comments doesn't help

Comment: sure, i updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT
  product, GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(gr) groups, COUNT(gr) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT product, gr FROM 
    (SELECT 'Prod1' AS product,'a' AS gr), 
    (SELECT 'Prod1' AS product,'b' AS gr),
    (SELECT 'Prod1' AS product,'c' AS gr), 
    (SELECT 'Prod1' AS product,'d' AS gr), 
    (SELECT 'Prod2' AS product,'a' AS gr), 
    (SELECT 'Prod2' AS product,'b' AS gr), 
    (SELECT 'Prod2' AS product,'d' AS gr), 
    (SELECT 'Prod3' AS product,'a' AS gr), 
    (SELECT 'Prod3' AS product,'b' AS gr), 
    (SELECT 'Prod3' AS product,'c' AS gr), 
    (SELECT 'Prod3' AS product,'d' AS gr)
) 
GROUP BY product 
HAVING NOT ',' + groups + ',' CONTAINS ',c,'
AND ',' + groups + ',' CONTAINS ',a,'
AND ',' + groups + ',' CONTAINS ',b,'
AND ',' + groups + ',' CONTAINS ',d,'
```

> but I'm looking for count of products that are not in group c but in
>   other groups.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(product) AS products
FROM (
  SELECT
    product, GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(gr) groups
  FROM (
    SELECT product, gr FROM 
      (SELECT 'Prod1' AS product,'a' AS gr), 
      (SELECT 'Prod1' AS product,'b' AS gr),
      (SELECT 'Prod1' AS product,'c' AS gr), 
      (SELECT 'Prod1' AS product,'d' AS gr), 
      (SELECT 'Prod2' AS product,'a' AS gr), 
      (SELECT 'Prod2' AS product,'b' AS gr), 
      (SELECT 'Prod2' AS product,'d' AS gr), 
      (SELECT 'Prod3' AS product,'a' AS gr), 
      (SELECT 'Prod3' AS product,'b' AS gr), 
      (SELECT 'Prod3' AS product,'c' AS gr), 
      (SELECT 'Prod3' AS product,'d' AS gr)
  ) 
  GROUP BY product 
  HAVING NOT ',' + groups + ',' CONTAINS ',c,'
  AND ',' + groups + ',' CONTAINS ',a,'
  AND ',' + groups + ',' CONTAINS ',b,'
  AND ',' + groups + ',' CONTAINS ',d,'
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail but I m looking for count of products that are not in group c but in other groups. from the above table. i should get a count as 1 which is product2 (not in group c)

Comment: Mikhail, Thanks but can you please explain me Having NOT part? Appreciate all your help

Comment: you group by product and for each product you group_concat together all groups separated by comma. than you look for those products which do not have c in that concatenation but do have a and do have b etc. - hope this makes sense to you. just play with code a little to understand it. run only inner selects etc. - play with it!

Comment: understood. I also gave OR instead of AND. Is there any way to include "null" or any other value that the group column can contain other than the mentioned one?

Comment: replace `GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(gr)` with `GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(IFNULL(gr, 'null'))` and treat 'null' as any other product name to exclude or include. for example `AND ',' + groups + ',' CONTAINS ',null,'`

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I wanted.

Comment: i am glad it helped :o)